# Sorting an array ref by its value in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, sorting, hash

I am extracting an XML and passing the value as reference.
The data in the reference is

```
$VAR1 = [ 
    {   
        'tender_data' => [
            {
                'total_mwh' => '191.4600',
                'retailer_code' => 'Origin',
                'client_num' => '20180516-03',
                'response_date' => '2018-05-22',
                'nmi' => 'NGGG000692',
                'month_name' => 'May',
                'ext_date' => '2018-5',
                'client_name' => 'Alpha Hotel Canberra',
                'result' => 'lost'
            }
        ],
        'state' => 'ACT'
    },  
    {   
        'tender_data' => [
            {
                'total_mwh' => '445.6410',
                'retailer_code' => 'ERM Power',
                'client_num' => '20110317-05',
                'response_date' => '2018-05-14',
                'nmi' => 'QB00457566',
                'month_name' => 'May',
                'ext_date' => '2018-5',
                'client_name' => 'Thunderbird Park',
                'result' => 'lost'
            },
            {
                'total_mwh' => '910.2670',
                'retailer_code' => 'AGL',
                'client_num' => '20140625-02',
                'response_date' => '2018-05-24',
                'nmi' => 'QB09015582',
                'month_name' => 'May',
                'ext_date' => '2018-5',
                'client_name' => 'Geewood Pty Ltd',
                'result' => 'undecided'
            },  

            {   
                'total_mwh' => '120.4290',
                'retailer_code' => 'AGL',
                'client_num' => '20180502-02',
                'response_date' => '2018-05-18',
                'nmi' => 'QB00493554',
                'month_name' => 'May',
                'ext_date' => '2018-5',
                'client_name' => 'Beaudesert Race Club Inc',
                'result' => 'won'
            },
        ],
        'state' => 'QLD'
    },
];
```

Now the issue is that I was trying to sort the hash by response_date, but I was not able to solve it.
I tried this code

```
$data = (sort { join('', (split '-', $data->{$a}->{response_date})[0,1,2]) cmp join('', (split '-', $data->{$b}->{response_date})[0,1,2]) } keys %{$data->{tender_data}});
```

But it was giving me error- Not a hash ref

So I tried with sorting array ref

```
$data = sort { join('', (split '-', $a)[0,1,2]) cmp join('', (split '-', $b)[0,1,2]) } @{$data};
```

But I was getting undef value. 
If I loop it using `foreach my $tender(@{$data}){}` I was getting the value inside data reference

Can someone please help me to sort the  it using **response_date**
I need this to be sorted

```
{
    'total_mwh' => '445.6410',
    'retailer_code' => 'ERM Power',
    'client_num' => '20110317-05',
    'response_date' => '2018-05-14',
    'nmi' => 'QB00457566',
    'month_name' => 'May',
    'ext_date' => '2018-5',
    'client_name' => 'Thunderbird Park',
    'result' => 'lost'
},
{
    'total_mwh' => '120.4290',
    'retailer_code' => 'AGL',
    'client_num' => '20180502-02',
    'response_date' => '2018-05-18',
    'nmi' => 'QB00493554',
    'month_name' => 'May',
    'ext_date' => '2018-5',
    'client_name' => 'Beaudesert Race Club Inc',
    'result' => 'won'
},

{
    'total_mwh' => '910.2670',
    'retailer_code' => 'AGL',
    'client_num' => '20140625-02',
    'response_date' => '2018-05-24',
    'nmi' => 'QB09015582',
    'month_name' => 'May',
    'ext_date' => '2018-5',
    'client_name' => 'Geewood Pty Ltd',
    'result' => 'undecided'
},
```

Comment: You have an array of hashes in which one of the keys has an array of hashes as the value. Can you be more specific about which you want to sort?
Could you provide an example of the expected output from the sort?

Comment: I need the last hash to be sorted by response date

Comment: What do you mean by the "_last hash_"?  Hashes are inherently unordered. You can print it sorted, or rearrange (sort) the hashrefs in an array, for example (what you seem to show). Can you edit the "sorted" example to show the whole data structure as you imagine it sorted? And please fix the indentation?

Comment: The second example does not have the same data as the first.  Is that an example of how you want it sorted, or yet another data set to sort?  Please edit to clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: This looks like `XML::Simple` output. Is it? There's reasons to use a different approach, which makes a lot of your problems a moot point.

Comment: yes its XML Simple output

Answer (score 2):

Given an array of hashes:

```
$data = [
  {'response_date' => '2018-05-18', 'client_name' => 'Beaudesert Race Club Inc'},
  {'response_date' => '2018-05-14', 'client_name' => 'Thunderbird Park'},
  {'response_date' => '2018-05-24', 'client_name' => 'Geewood Pty Ltd'},
];
```

You can sort it by the `'response_date'` key with:

```
sort {$$a{response_date} cmp $$b{response_date}} @$data
```

For example:

```
# perl -MData::Dumper
$data = [
  {'response_date' => '2018-05-18', 'client_name' => 'Beaudesert Race Club Inc'},
  {'response_date' => '2018-05-14', 'client_name' => 'Thunderbird Park'},
  {'response_date' => '2018-05-24', 'client_name' => 'Geewood Pty Ltd'},
];
print Dumper([sort {$$a{response_date} cmp $$b{response_date}} @$data]);
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'client_name' => 'Thunderbird Park',
            'response_date' => '2018-05-14'
          },
          {
            'response_date' => '2018-05-18',
            'client_name' => 'Beaudesert Race Club Inc'
          },
          {
            'client_name' => 'Geewood Pty Ltd',
            'response_date' => '2018-05-24'
          }
        ];
```

Comment: my var value is var1 = [{ 'tender_data' => [ { 'client_num' => '20110317-05', 'response_date' => '2018-05-14', }, { 'client_num' => '20140625-02', 'response_date' => '2018-05-24', }, { 'client_num' => '20180502-02', 'response_date' => '2018-05-18', }, ], 'state' => 'QLD' },] I tried but not getting the value ,shows $var1 = undef

Comment: It's much more readable to use the arrow operator `sort {$a->{response_date} cmp $b->{response_date}} @$data` or at least additional braces `sort {${$a}{response_date} cmp ${$b}{response_date}} @$data`